# SQL sum two tables in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have `users` table with all the information about my users, with an `id` column.
I also have 2 other tables with points each user got in a game they played. Lets call them `game1` and `game2`.

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jos8nbwwAD3C2tExiw79pQ/1)

```sql
create table users (id text, username text);
create table game1 (user_id text, points int);
create table game2 (user_id text, points int);
```

A user can have more than one row in each table.
I want to sum up all the points each user got.

Here's an example:

```
-- Users table
id      username
user1   Adam
user2   John
user3   Martha

-- game1 table
user_id points
user1   10
user2   9
user1   8
user1   7

--game2 table
user_id points
user2   1
user3   2
user1   3
user1   4
```

When I try to use two left joins I get duplicate values and nulls... obviously I'm doing something wrong here...

here's my sql:

```
-- try to sum all games points for each player
select u.id, u.username, sum(game1.points) + sum(game2.points) as sum_all_games_points
from users u
  LEFT JOIN game1 ON game1.user_id = u.id
  LEFT JOIN game2 ON game2.user_id = u.id
group by u.id, u.username;
```

The result for this query is:

```
id      username    sum_all_games_points
user2   John        10
user3   Martha      null
user1   Adam        71
```

The results that I'm expecting to get is this (No need for user id):

```
username    sum_all_games_points
John        32                -- This is the sum of (10 + 8 + 7 + 3 + 4)
Martha      2                 -- Only one game played on game2
Adam        10                -- 9 points from game1 and 1 point from game2
```

Comment: You should not be storing game scores in separate tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That's very much obvious. This a simplified version of what I'm asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting strange results for a couple of reasons. First your `JOIN`s are creating multiple rows for each user so some values are being double-counted. Second, you need to use `COALESCE` to convert `NULL` values to 0 to avoid getting a `NULL` output from the addition. This should work:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, 
       COALESCE(g1.points, 0) + COALESCE(g2.points) AS sum_all_games_points
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, SUM(points) AS points
           FROM game1
           GROUP BY user_id) g1 ON g1.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, SUM(points) AS points
           FROM game2
           GROUP BY user_id) g2 ON g2.user_id = u.id
```

Output:

```
id      username    sum_all_games_points
user1   Adam        32
user2   John        10
user3   Martha      2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e8d15556c48a69b1413ce7bb182ec820)

Comment: Thanks! your solution looks like the right way to go, but looking at @TheNikita `UNION` I'm not sure which is the "correct" way to do... both solve my problem...
WDYT about the `Union` solution?

Comment: @gilamran both will work, performance wise probably similar too (I'd be interested in hearing your results if you benchmark them). Gordon's comment to your question is worth noting as well, it would probably be better to have a single game table with a third column which specified what the game was.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to union tables game1 and game2 and join them to initial table after that.

```
SELECT 
    U.ID, 
    U.USERNAME,
    COALESCE(GG.POINTS, 0) AS ALL_POINTS
FROM
    USERS U
LEFT JOIN            
    (SELECT 
        USER_ID, 
        SUM(POINTS) AS POINTS
    FROM           
        (SELECT * FROM GAME1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM GAME2) G
    GROUP BY 
        USER_ID) GG
ON 
    GG.USER_ID = U.ID
```